# JavaScript enlace externo no funciona

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando en esto de la programación con HTMl y JavaScript pero estoy probando el siguiente código y no sé porque no me funciona cuando lo agrego a un fichero externo.
Cuando pongo el script en el HTML no hay problema y funciona, pero no sé el motivo por el cual no funciona de la otra forma.
La estructura que tengo de carpetas es la que sigue:
[image: Estructura de carpetas]

A ver si alguien me ayuda. Gracias.

### CÓDIGO HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!--<script language="Javascript">
            function mostrar(nombreCapa){
                document.getElementById(nombreCapa).style.visibility="visible";
            }

            function ocultar(nombreCapa){
                document.getElementById(nombreCapa).style.visibility="hidden";
            }
        </script>-->

</head>
<body>
    <script src="funciones_JS.js"></script>
        <p id="mielemento">Parrafo a ocultar</p>
        <input type="button" name="boton" value ="OCULTAR" onClick="ocultar('mielemento')">
        <input type="button" name="boton" value ="MOSTRAR" onClick="mostrar('mielemento')">    
</body>
```

### JAVASCRITP

```
<script language="javascript">
    function ocultar(nombreElemento){
    document.getElementById(nombreElemento).style.visibility = "hidden"
    }

    function mostrar(nombreElemento){
        document.getElementById(nombreElmento).style.visibility ="visible"
    }
    
</script>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado. El archivo funciones_JS.js contenía un error en el scritp. Sobran las etiquetas  y , con lo que el archivo quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
 function ocultar(nombreElemento){
    document.getElementById(nombreElemento).style.visibility = "hidden"
    }

    function mostrar(nombreElemento){
        document.getElementById(nombreElmento).style.visibility ="visible"
    }
```

Comment: El error es porque escribiste mal:

El nombre que pasaste en el parámetro de la función mostrar es nombreElemento pero pasaste al getElementById nombreElmento... faltando la "e"

Answer (score 0):

Estate seguro de que el archivo no está en ninguna carpeta, sino no lo detectara, ademas ese código se puede pasar para que lo entiendas mejor, es la misma función pero más abreviado y sencillo

```javascript
   function ocultar(nombreElemento){
    document.getElementById(nombreElemento).style.display = "none"
    }

    function mostrar(nombreElemento){
        document.getElementById(nombreElemento).style.display = "block"
    }
```

También te habías confundido y puesto la funcion mostrar con la id nombreElmento en vez de nombreElemento